# Run full screen on HTC Touch HD2 with Android 2.3

Tags: android, opengl-es

I have an HTC Touch HD2 with Android 2.3.4. I use NetBeans 7.1 with Android SDK 2.3, running on Mac OS 10.5. I downloaded the Google API for this OS, and created example apps, but I can't run them at full screen. I found a answer that says to add the following lines:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // (NEW)
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); // (NEW)
```

But still it's continuously running in this way:

[image]

This is how look my manifest after adding the support-screen tag (not working):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.tejon"
  android:versionCode="1"
     android:versionName="1.0">
      <application android:label="@string/app_name" >
          <activity android:name="Prueba2FullScreen"
                    android:label="@string/app_name">
              <intent-filter>
                  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
              </intent-filter>
            </activity>

      </application>

      <supports-screens
      android:smallScreens="true"
      android:normalScreens="true"
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
  </manifest>
```

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project and re-building your application?

Answer (score 0):

Setup your viewport with the screen's width and height. `GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);` or `GL10.glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);`

EDIT: The above is my initial reaction. However, I remember running into a very similar issue last summer. The fix was to add some stuff to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<supports-screens
 android:smallScreens="true"
 android:normalScreens="true"
 android:largeScreens="true"
 android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I added the lines but my problem continues